# Iterating object to array useState in a loop

Tags: reactjs, iteration, ethereum, use-state

I am working on React project, I have problem with dynamic component creating with `useState`;

First, I am getting data address from Ethereum and according to this address in a `for` loop getting data from IPFS, and I want to save this data to useState array of object.

This is function that getting address from Ethereum:

```
patientstorage.deployed().then(function(contractInstance){
    contractInstance.getPatientContractAddressByPatientName(usnameByte32).then(function(result){
        const PatientContract = new web3.eth.Contract(Patient.abi,result)
        PatientContract.methods.getConsultationsIpfsList().call({from: ethereum.selectedAddress}).then(function(result){
            console.log("Consul IPFSes:", result)
            for(var i=0; i<result.length; i++){
                console.log(ethers.utils.toUtf8String(result[i]))
                IPFSREADER(result[i]);
            }
        })
    });
})
```

and this is my `IPFSREADER` function here, getting data from IPFS and setting `useState`:

```
const [consul, setConsul] = useState([])
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

function IPFSREADER(element){
    let convertedIPFSaddress = ethers.utils.toUtf8String(element)
    ipfs.cat(convertedIPFSaddress).then(function(result){
        console.log('ipfs.cat result:', result)
        let cons = result.toString('utf8')
        const parsed = JSON.parse(cons);
        console.log("cons:",parsed)
        setConsul([parsed,...consul])
        console.log("cons:",consul)
    })
}
```

`consul` is my all data which is read from IPFS storage. When i printing this like this:

```
<Card bg="dark">
  <Card.Header>
    {consul.date} {consul.time}
  </Card.Header>
  <Card.Body>
    <blockquote className="blockquote mb-0">
      <p> Doctor:{consul.doctorName} </p>
      <p> Address:{consul.addr} </p>
      <p> Disease:{consul.disease} </p>
      <p> medicine:{consul.medicine} </p>
      <footer className="blockquote-footer">
        Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
      </footer>
    </blockquote>
  </Card.Body>
</Card>;
```

Now, **problem** is here, when i want to create a Object Array `useState`, with `setConsul([parsed,...consul])` this code in `IPFSREADER` it always return empty array, therefore, I cant use this `useState` for rendering dynamic component with `map`. Can you help me what can I do for creating the array of objects?

Comment: Are all of these elements within a single file component?

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri yes sir.

Comment: 1 important thing to point out here is that state updates are async so your console.log after setConsul won't show you the updated array. However the data should reflect correctly in render. Also you defined `consul` as an array but try to access it like an object `consul.date` which isn't correct

Comment: When i get data from IPFS, there is an object, which has `object.date`, `object.doctorName` etc. My problem is can not correctly adding this object to `consul` array. I want to add data object to consul array which is get from `IPFSREADER(result[i])`. (`result` is an array, containing addresses.)

Comment: But are you iterating over the consul array while rendering

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri yes